# Split string into two dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

How do I make the split string into 2 dimensional array in C# Console App?

```
char[,] table2x2 = new char[2, 2]; 
string myString = "11A23A4A5A"; 
string[] splitA = myString.Split(new char[] { 'A' });
```

so that the output would be

```
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[0, 0]); //output: 11
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[0, 1]); //output: 23
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[1, 0]); //output: 4
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[1, 1]); //output: 5
```

Returned back to original question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the type of `table2x2` elements would be `char`, you never get that output. You should change it to `string` or `int` (that requires parsing).

Comment: After your edit, I do not understand the indexes for `table3x3`. How are you constructing the output?

Comment: I made few errors indeed. So each of the character in the string is inside the array. However, only the digit after the 'A' has been split will be displayed. The rest will be blank.

Comment: The indexes now make sense, but the blanks does not! Do you exactly want the first digits after any `A` or any digits that come after `A`s? Neither is like your expected output, and I don't understand the output.

Comment: The first digit after any A will be inside the array. I have made several attempt such as `for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < 4; i++, j = j + splitA[i].Length)
            {
                table3x3[0, j] = splitA[i][0].ToString();
            }` But I really have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: Can you please explain the blanks? Please edit the question and explain exactly how your satisfactory output is created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// your code, char[,] replaced by string[,]
string[,] table2x2 = new string[2, 2];  
string myString = "11A23A4A5A"; 
string[] splitA = myString.Split(new char[] { 'A' }); 

// this converts splitA into a 2D array
// Math.Min is used to avoid filling past the array bounds
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(splitA.Length, 2*2); i++) {
    table2x2[i / 2, i % 2] = splitA[i];
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm for my previous question. Unfortunately, I changed the question format.

Comment: @Asmo: Well, then I suggest that you start a new question, because now the answer does not fit the question anymore. ;-)

Comment: I was thinking of making a new question. But it seems like there is a little modification. So I decided to edit and modify the question. Would there be similar approach?

Comment: @Asmo: It's not at all clear how you want to assign the values to the array. I think it's better to revert this question to its original form and start a new question *with more details on which string should become which array*.