# Putting the first digit of split string into two dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, split

in C# console app, how do you put the first digit of split string into two dimensional array?

```
string[,] table3x3 = new string[3, 3];  
string myString = "11A23A4A5A87A5"; 
string[] splitA = myString.Split(new char[] { 'A' });
```

Let's say I have 2-dimensional array of 3x3 and a string with numbers and a vowel. I split them so that I can put them inside the 2Darray. What kind of loop should I include so that the output would be

```
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[0, 0]); //output: blank
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[0, 1]); //output: blank
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[0, 2]); //output: 2
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[1, 0]); //output: blank
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[1, 1]); //output: 4
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[1, 2]); //output: 5
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[2, 0]); //output: 8
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[2, 1]); //output: blank
Console.WriteLine(table3x3[2, 2]); //output: 5
```

Visually, the output would be like:

```
[ ][ ][2]
[ ][4][5]
[8][ ][5]
```

There are 9 numbers and 5 vowels inside the string. It returns the first digit of split string into specific 2Darray according to their sequences.

Comment: The logic isn't quite clear to me... Where's `11` and `87` in the output array?

Comment: why is your result not - - 2 / - 4 5 / 8 - 5

Comment: @mellamokb yes, it was not clear indeed. I changed the output.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus that is the output I want

Comment: Shouldn't there also be a `[1]` at the beginning?

Comment: uh no. Since there is no "A" before 1

Comment: @GrantWinney: Exactly, I think that's what isn't quite clear.

Comment: @GrantWinney that is true. but if I use `Console.WriteLine(splitA[0][0]);` it only returns 1 instead of 11

Comment: Console.Write("[ ][ ][2]\n[ ][4][5]\n[8][ ][5]")... @Asmo - please edit your question so it is clear how you want to split the string and what portion of the task you have problem with. And if it is homework - add corresponding tag so people can adjust answers (may be good idea to post whole task in this case :))

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov visually, that would be that kind of output (just to give the people better understanding). but I want them inside the 2Darray instead. It is a project, so I just create a new simple case rather than posting the whole code :D

Comment: Looks like condition is "cell is empty unless digit is prefixed by 'A', in which case next value put in the cell". Answered by mellamokb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string into two dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851886/split-string-into-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string[,] table3x3 = new string[3, 3];  
string myString = "11A23A4A5A87A5";

int stringIndex = -1;
bool immediatelyFollowsA = false;
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        while (myString[++stringIndex] == 'A')
        {
            immediatelyFollowsA = true;
        }

        if (immediatelyFollowsA)
        {
            table3x3[row,col] = myString[stringIndex].ToString();
            immediatelyFollowsA = false;
        }
    }
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/X0LdF

---

Or alternatively, adding to your original starting point:

```
string[,] table3x3 = new string[3, 3];  
string myString = "11A23A4A5A87A5";
string[] splitA = myString.Split(new char[] { 'A' });

int index = 0;
bool first = true;
foreach (string part in splitA)
{
    int row = index / 3;
    int col = index % 3;

    if (!first)
    {
        table3x3[row, col] = part[0].ToString();
    }

    index += part.Length;
    first = false;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/7sKuR

Comment: +1. Almost exactly the way I was trying to do write it... Also mine would have bug with indexing as I tried to do something like `table3x3[stringIndex%3, stringIndex/3]= myString[stringIndex]`...

Comment: but if I `Console.WriteLine(table3x3[0, 2]);` it should give 2 as the output. How do I make them inside the 2Darray?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  If I put `Console.WriteLine(table3x3[0, 2]);` at the end of either of my code examples, I get `2` as output.